# vector3 math module

Tags: performance, c, coordinate-system

I'm writing a little math module in C to handle vectors and matrices. This will be column-major style but right now I've only finished the basics of the vector functions and wanted some feedback on optimization tips, naming conventions, etc. This is C so no real function overloading. I would like to keep it C style.

#### vec3f.h

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "math.h"

const double m_PI = 3.14159265359;

typedef struct vec3f
{
    double p[3];
}vec3f;

vec3f* vec3fx(double x, double y, double z);
vec3f* vec3fv(vec3f* v3);
vec3f  vec3fs(double x, double y, double z);
void vec3fadd(vec3f* out, struct vec3f* a, struct vec3f* b);
void vec3fsub(vec3f* out, struct vec3f* a, struct vec3f* b);
void vec3fmul(vec3f* out, struct vec3f* a, struct vec3f* b);

void vec3fnegate(vec3f* out);

void vec3fscale(vec3f* out, double a);
void vec3fscaleu(vec3f* out, double x, double y, double z);
void vec3fscalex(vec3f* out, double a);
void vec3fscaley(vec3f* out, double a);
void vec3fscalez(vec3f* out, double a);

void vec3flen(double* out, vec3f* in);

void toDegrees(double* out, double angleInRadians);
void toRadians(double* out, double angleInDegrees);

void vec3fdot(double* out, vec3f* a, vec3f* b);
void vec3fcross(vec3f* out, vec3f* a, vec3f* b);

void vec3fnorm(vec3f* out, vec3f* in);
void vec3fdist(double* out, vec3f* a, vec3f* b);

void vec3fangle(double* out, vec3f* a, vec3f* b);
```

#### vec3f.c

```
#include "vec3f.h"

vec3f* vec3fx(double x, double y, double z)
{
    vec3f* v = (vec3f*)malloc(sizeof(vec3f));
    v->p[0] = x;
    v->p[1] = y;
    v->p[2] = z;
    return v;
}

vec3f* vec3fv(vec3f* v3)
{
    vec3f* v = (vec3f*)malloc(sizeof(vec3f));
    v->p[0] = v3->p[0];
    v->p[1] = v3->p[1];
    v->p[2] = v3->p[2];
    return v;
}

void vec3fadd(vec3f* out, vec3f* a, vec3f* b)
{
    out->p[0] = a->p[0] + b->p[0];
    out->p[1] = a->p[1] + b->p[1];
    out->p[2] = a->p[2] + b->p[2];
}

void vec3fsub(vec3f* out, vec3f* a, vec3f* b)
{
    out->p[0] = a->p[0] - b->p[0];
    out->p[1] = a->p[1] - b->p[1];
    out->p[2] = a->p[2] - b->p[2];
}

void vec3fmul(vec3f* out, vec3f* a, vec3f* b)
{
    out->p[0] = a->p[0] * b->p[0];
    out->p[1] = a->p[1] * b->p[1];
    out->p[2] = a->p[2] * b->p[2];
}

void vec3fnegate(vec3f* out)
{
    out->p[0] = -out->p[0];
    out->p[1] = -out->p[1];
    out->p[2] = -out->p[2];
}

void vec3fscale(vec3f* out, double a)
{
    out->p[0] *= a;
    out->p[1] *= a;
    out->p[2] *= a;
}

void vec3fscaleu(vec3f* out, double x, double y, double z)
{
    out->p[0] *= x;
    out->p[1] *= y;
    out->p[2] *= z;
}

void vec3fscalex(vec3f* out, double a)
{
    out->p[0] *= a;
}

void vec3fscaley(vec3f* out, double a)
{
    out->p[1] *= a;
}

void vec3fscalez(vec3f* out, double a)
{
    out->p[2] *= a;
}

void vec3flen(double* out, vec3f* in)
{
    double res = 0;

    res += in->p[0] * in->p[0];
    res += in->p[1] * in->p[1];
    res += in->p[2] * in->p[2];

    *out = sqrt(res);
}


void toDegrees(double* out, double angleInRadians)
{
    *out = angleInRadians * (double)(180.0/m_PI);
}

void toRadians(double* out, double angleInDegrees)
{
    *out = angleInDegrees * (double)(m_PI/180.0);
}

void vec3fdot(double* out, vec3f* a, vec3f* b)
{
    double total = 0;
    total += a->p[0] * b->p[0];
    total += a->p[1] * b->p[1];
    total += a->p[2] * b->p[2];
    *out = total;
}
void vec3fcross(vec3f* out, vec3f* a, vec3f* b)
{
    out->p[0] = a->p[1] * b->p[2] - b->p[1] * a->p[2];
    out->p[1] = a->p[2] * b->p[0] - b->p[2] * a->p[0];
    out->p[2] = a->p[0] * b->p[1] - b->p[0] * a->p[1];
}

void vec3fnorm(vec3f* out, vec3f* in)
{
    double t = 0;
    vec3flen(&t, in);
    out->p[0] = in->p[0]/t;
    out->p[1] = in->p[1]/t;
    out->p[2] = in->p[2]/t;
}

void vec3fdist(double* out, vec3f* a, vec3f*b)
{
    vec3f tmp;
    vec3fsub(&tmp, b, a);
    vec3flen(out, &tmp);
}

void vec3fangle(double* out, vec3f* a, vec3f* b)
{
    double tmp;
    vec3fdot(&tmp, a, b);
    *out = acos(tmp);
}
```

Comment: You must normalize vectors to calculate angle.

Comment: @vnp:  good point!  I've fixed my answer to include that.

Comment: @user1610950, if you have a second version of the code that you want reviewed, post it as a new question, don't edit it into the existing question.

Comment: See [How to post a follow-up question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-post-a-follow-up-question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be generally well-written code.  I have a few observations which may help you improve your code.

### Separate interface from implementation

The interface is the part in the `vec3f.h` file and the implementation is in the `vec3f.c` file.  Users of this code should be able to read and understand everything they need from the implementation file.  That means that only `#include`s essential to being able to understand the interface should be in the `.h` file.  In this case, none are needed, so the `#include` lines should be deleted from the `.h` file.  Also...

### Use all appropriate `#include`s

The implementation file (the `.c` file) does need some `#include` files but they should be in angle brackets and not quotes.  When you write `#include "math.h"` it is different from `#include <math.h>`.  For standard headers, you should use the `<>` form.  If you're not sure about the difference, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) for more detail.  In this case, `vec3f.c` should start with:

```
#include "vec3f.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
```

### Use include guards

There should be an include guard in the `.h` file.  That is, start the file with:

```
#ifndef VEC3F_H
#define VEC3F_H
// file contents go here
#endif // VEC3F_H
```

### Omit spurious declarations

The `vec3f.h` file includes a declaration for `vec3fs` but no implementation exists in the `vec3f.c` file.  The declaration should be omitted.

### Use `const` where practical

For a number of the operations, the `vec3f` structures passed in are unaltered.  That's good design, but you should make it explicit.  So for example instead of this:

```
void vec3fadd(vec3f* out, struct vec3f* a, struct vec3f* b);
```

Use this instead:

```
void vec3fadd(vec3f* out, const vec3f* a, const vec3f* b);
```

Note that this change also uses the next suggestion.

### Use defined `typedef` where practical

The declarations for `vec3fadd`, `vec3fsub` and `vec3fmul` should use the the typedef'd `vec3f` rather than the longer `struct vec3f`.  Both are correct, but since you've created the `typedef`, it makes sense to also use it consistently.

### Provide a means for non-heap allocation

Perhaps your unwritten `vec3fs` function was intended to do this, but there is currently no way to initialize values for an stack-based `vec3f`.  I'd recommend adding one like this:

```
vec3f* vec3fs(vec3f* v, double x, double y, double z)
{
    if (v != NULL) {
        v->p[0] = x;
        v->p[1] = y;
        v->p[2] = z;
    }
    return v;
}
```

### Check the return value of `malloc`

If the program runs out of memory, a call to `malloc` can fail.  The indication for this is that the call will return a `NULL` pointer.  You should check for this and avoid dereferencing a `NULL` pointer (which typically causes a program crash).  For example, using the `vec3fs` above, you could rewrite `vec3fx` as:

```
vec3f* vec3fx(double x, double y, double z)
{
    vec3f* v = malloc(sizeof(vec3f));
    return vec3fs(v, x, y, z);
}
```

Note also that the cast is not required since `malloc` returns a `void *`.

### Don't pointlessly initialize variables

The current code includes this function:

```
void vec3fdot(double* out, vec3f* a, vec3f* b)
{
    double total = 0;
    total += a->p[0] * b->p[0];
    total += a->p[1] * b->p[1];
    total += a->p[2] * b->p[2];
    *out = total;
}
```

Consider instead this minor rewrite of `vec3fdot`:

```
double vec3fdot(const vec3f* a, const vec3f* b)
{
    return a->p[0] * b->p[0]
         + a->p[1] * b->p[1]
         + a->p[2] * b->p[2];
}
```

### Return something useful from functions

The way the functions are currently written, most return `void` but this prevents one from writing useful construct such as:

```
toDegrees(vec3fangle(vec1, vec2));
```

To support this, you could rewrite those two functions as:

```
double toDegrees(double angleInRadians)
{
    return angleInRadians * (double)(180.0/m_PI);
}
double vec3fangle(const vec3f* a, const vec3f* b)
{
    return acos(vec3fdot(a, b)/(vec3flen(a)*vec3flen(b)));
}
```

Similarly, I'd recommend that each function that takes a `vec3f *out` as the first parameter should also return it. This would make your `vec3f.h` file look like this:

#### vec3f.h

```
#ifndef VEC3F_H
#define VEC3F_H
const double m_PI = 3.14159265359;

typedef struct vec3f
{
    double p[3];
}vec3f;

vec3f* vec3fx(double x, double y, double z);
vec3f* vec3fv(vec3f* v3);
vec3f* vec3fs(vec3f* v, double x, double y, double z);
vec3f* vec3fadd(vec3f* out, const vec3f* a, const vec3f* b);
vec3f* vec3fsub(vec3f* out, const vec3f* a, const vec3f* b);
vec3f* vec3fmul(vec3f* out, const vec3f* a, const vec3f* b);

vec3f* vec3fnegate(vec3f* out);

vec3f* vec3fscale(vec3f* out, double a);
vec3f* vec3fscaleu(vec3f* out, double x, double y, double z);
vec3f* vec3fscalex(vec3f* out, double a);
vec3f* vec3fscaley(vec3f* out, double a);
vec3f* vec3fscalez(vec3f* out, double a);

double vec3flen(const vec3f* in);

double toDegrees(double angleInRadians);
double toRadians(double angleInDegrees);

double vec3fdot(const vec3f* a, const vec3f* b);
vec3f* vec3fcross(vec3f* out, const vec3f* a, const vec3f* b);

vec3f* vec3fnorm(vec3f* out, const vec3f* in);
double vec3fdist(const vec3f* a, const vec3f* b);

double vec3fangle(const vec3f* a, const vec3f* b);
#endif // VEC3F_H
```

### Consider providing "in-place" operations as well

Your interface already includes the more generic form in which the output vector is different from either input vector, but it would likely be handy to have an explicit "in-place" version for your operators as well.  For example,

```
vec3f* vec3fadd(vec3f* a, const vec3f* b) 
{
    return vec3fadd(a, a, b);
}
```

Similarly, you may want to provide non-in-place versions of functions such as the scaling functions:

```
vec3f* vec3fscale(vec3f* out, const vec3f* a, double f);
```

### Consider making the dimensionality generic

If you ever wanted to make a 2D or 4D point, consider how it might be done:

```
double vec2flen(const vec2f* in)
{
    return sqrt(in->p[0] * in->p[0]
              + in->p[1] * in->p[1]);
}
double vec3flen(const vec3f* in)
{
    return sqrt(in->p[0] * in->p[0]
              + in->p[1] * in->p[1]
              + in->p[2] * in->p[2]);
}
double vec4flen(const vec4f* in)
{
    return sqrt(in->p[0] * in->p[0]
              + in->p[1] * in->p[1]
              + in->p[2] * in->p[2]
              + in->p[3] * in->p[3]);
}
```

It might be useful to consider writing these generically in terms of the dimensionality of `p`.  That might be either a fixed compile-time value as shown below or potentially as a member of a generic `vecf` structure.

```
double vecflen(const vecf* in)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < DIMENSIONS; ++i) {
        sum += in->p[i] * in->p[i];
    }
    return sqrt(sum);
}
```

### Consider removing allocating functions

Instead of the functions which allocate memory and then initialize, I think it may be better to leave out the allocation, since it's nothing more than `malloc(sizeof(vec3f))` anyway.  Doing so will prevent "hidden" memory allocations since both the allocation and freeing of that memory will happen in some calling function using the usual memory allocation/deallocation calls.

### Consider adding a projection function

One handy function that does not appear in your list is a projection function:

```
//  calculate the projection of b onto a 
vec3f* vec3fproj(vec3f* out, const vec3f* a, const vec3f* b)
{
    vec3fcopy(out, a);
    double alen = vec3flen(a);
    return vec3fscale(out, vec3fdot(a, b)/(alen*alen));
}
```

Comment: Per the comment by @vnp, I have updated my answer to include a slightly more correct answer for the `vect3fangle`, but it will fail if either vector has zero length.  I'll leave handling that error to the original programmer.

Comment: This was really helpful, I reworked the code a bit and I'll post it above by editing my original question. I added the projection function as well. I avoided added the generic code because I don't just want to add code just to put it there. I wasn't quite sure about how to remove the allocation function so I just left those as is. I also added some in place functions as well. A big issue that I have now is a naming convention that seems rational but that's maybe personal choice. I also wanted to avoid returning these struct and added the typedef.